# My query is taking too much time to execute?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, symfony, symfony1

I am fetching user leads from database having million records and the fetching is taking 5-10 seconds. How can i make it faster? Should i switch from ORM to direct query or can i do something with the current ORM?

```
public static function getBtqUsers($search_params) {
    $criteria = new Criteria();

    $criteria->clearSelectColumns();
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.id as id");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.drid as drid");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.name as name");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.email as email");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.active as active");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.lead_from as lead_from");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.source as source");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.http_referer as http_referer");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.sms_status as sms_status");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.telefon as telefon");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.datain as datain");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.kall as kall");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.ip_address as ip_address");

    $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(btq_user_track_blog_video.counter) as total_video_viewed");

    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.id as dr_id");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drname as dr_name");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drphone as dr_phone");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.initials as dr_initials");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drmail as dr_mail");

    $criteria->addSelectColumn("event_data.btq_user_id as event_user_id");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=2, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_video_viewed");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=1, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_blog_viewed");

    $criteria->addSelectColumn("state.pres as pres");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("state.state as state");

    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.type as choice_type");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.opt_value as choice_value");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.opt_text as choice_text");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.pfu_customer_id as pfu_customer_id");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("lead_schedule.id as schedule_id");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("lead_schedule.created_at as schedule_date");

    $criteria->addJoin(self::STATE_ID, StatePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(self::BTQ_USER_SALES_CHOICE_ID, BtqUserSalesChoicePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, LeadSchedulePeer::LEAD_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(self::DRID, BtqDoctorsPeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, BtqUserTrackBlogVideoPeer::USER_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
//    $criteria->addJoin(self::DRID, BtqDoctorPfuAdminPeer::BTQ_DOCTOR_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
//    $criteria->addExtraJoin(BtqDoctorPfuAdminPeer::PFU_ADMIN_ID, PfuCustomerPeer::PFU_ADMIN_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN, " AND " . PfuCustomerPeer::EMAIL . " = " . self::EMAIL);

    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, EventDataPeer::BTQ_USER_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);

    //$criteria->addGroupByColumn(self::ID);
    $criteria->addGroupByColumn(self::EMAIL);
    //$criteria->addGroupByColumn(EventDataPeer::BTQ_USER_ID);
    $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::IS_DUMMY_DETAIL, "1", Criteria::NOT_EQUAL);

    $criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::DATAIN);
    if (!empty($search_params)) {
      foreach ($search_params as $key => $param) {

        if (trim($param)) {
          $param = addslashes($param);

          switch ($key) {

            case 'name':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::NAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'email':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::EMAIL, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'dr_name':
              $criteria->add(BtqDoctorsPeer::DRNAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'phone':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::TELEFON, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'lead_from':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::LEAD_FROM, $param, Criteria::EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'start_date':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param . " 00:00:00", Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'end_date':
              $criteria->addAnd(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param . " 23:59:59", Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'location':
              if ($param == "Local")
                $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::IN);
              else if ($param == "Non Local")
                $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::NOT_IN);
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }//FB::log($criteria);
    return $criteria;
//    return self::doSelectStmt($criteria)->fetchAll();
  }
```

I am trying to fetch the 2 days back records but still it's taking too much time.

**Code i am passing as parameter to searchParams:**

```
> $searchParams = array('start_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2
> days')) , 'end_date' => date("Y-m-d"));
>       $this->pager->setCriteria(btqAdminBtqUserPeer::getBtqUsers($searchParams));
>       $this->form->setDefault('start_date', $searchParams['start_date']);
>       $this->form->setDefault('end_date', $searchParams['end_date']);
```

**RAW SQL:**

```
SELECT  btq_user.id as id, btq_user.drid as drid, btq_user.name as name,
        btq_user.email as email, btq_user.active as active, btq_user.lead_from as lead_from,
        btq_user.source as source, btq_user.http_referer as http_referer,
        btq_user.sms_status as sms_status, btq_user.telefon as telefon,
        btq_user.datain as datain, btq_user.kall as kall, btq_user.ip_address as ip_address,
        count(btq_user_track_blog_video.counter) as total_video_viewed,
        btq_doctors.id as dr_id, btq_doctors.drname as dr_name,
        btq_doctors.drphone as dr_phone, btq_doctors.initials as dr_initials,
        btq_doctors.drmail as dr_mail, event_data.btq_user_id as event_user_id,
        count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=2, event_data.event_parent_id,
                        null)) as kms_total_video_viewed,
        count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=1,
                        event_data.event_parent_id, null)
             ) as kms_total_blog_viewed,
        state.pres as pres, state.state as state, btq_user_sales_choice.type as choice_type,
        btq_user_sales_choice.opt_value as choice_value, btq_user_sales_choice.opt_text as choice_text,
        btq_user.pfu_customer_id as pfu_customer_id, lead_schedule.id as schedule_id,
        lead_schedule.created_at as schedule_date
    FROM  btq_user
    LEFT JOIN  state  ON (btq_user.STATE_ID=state.ID)
    LEFT JOIN  btq_user_sales_choice
         ON (btq_user.BTQ_USER_SALES_CHOICE_ID=btq_user_sales_choice.ID)
    LEFT JOIN  lead_schedule  ON (btq_user.ID=lead_schedule.LEAD_ID)
    LEFT JOIN  btq_doctors  ON (btq_user.DRID=btq_doctors.ID)
    LEFT JOIN  btq_user_track_blog_video
         ON (btq_user.ID=btq_user_track_blog_video.USER_ID)
    LEFT JOIN  event_data  ON (btq_user.ID=event_data.BTQ_USER_ID)
    WHERE  btq_user.IS_DUMMY_DETAIL<>1
      AND  (btq_user.DATAIN>='2008-03-11 00:00:00'
      AND   btq_user.DATAIN<='2018-03-13 23:59:59'
           )
    GROUP BY  btq_user.EMAIL
    ORDER BY  btq_user.DATAIN DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

View:

```
<?php
      foreach ($pager->getResults() as $row):
        $customer = btqAdminBtqUserPeer::getQuizUserGroupByEmaiIdAndTelephone($row['email'], $params);
        if ($customer['quizes']) {
          $quizzes = explode(",", $customer['quizes']);
          $quizzes_count = count($quizzes);
        } else {
          $quizzes = '';
          $quizzes_count = 0;
        }

        $scheduleClass = ($row['schedule_date']) ? 'schedule_available':'schedule_empty';
        ?>
```

From the Template/View I'm calling the below function which is slowing the query to much:

```
public static function getQuizUserGroupByEmaiIdAndTelephone($userEmailId, $searchParameters) {
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addSelectColumn(" IF( COUNT(btq_user.id) > 1, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(btq_user.id),'~',CONCAT(btq_user.datain)) , null) as quizes");
    $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::EMAIL, $userEmailId, Criteria::EQUAL);
    $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::IS_DUMMY_DETAIL, "1", Criteria::NOT_EQUAL);
    if (!empty($searchParameters)) {
      foreach ($searchParameters as $key => $param) {

        if (trim($param)) {
          $param = addslashes($param);

          switch ($key) {

            case 'name':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::NAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'email':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::EMAIL, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'dr_name':
              $criteria->add(BtqDoctorsPeer::DRNAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'phone':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::TELEFON, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
              break;

            case 'lead_from':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::LEAD_FROM, $param, Criteria::EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'start_date':
              $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param . " 00:00:00", Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'end_date':
              $criteria->addAnd(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param . " 23:59:59", Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
              break;

            case 'location':
              $criteria->addJoin(self::STATE_ID, StatePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
              if ($param == "Local")
                $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::IN);
              else if ($param == "Non Local")
                $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::NOT_IN);
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
$criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::DATAIN);
return self::doSelectStmt($criteria)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If anything else is required let me know i will edit the question and description.

Thanks

Comment: Create a view for all table joins and do filter on that view

Comment: Check if it's the query to database that take time (like a where condition without index). For that you'll have to profile the SQL join parts of your query. If your query return thousands of rows, maybe it's the object hydratation that take time, and you could consider using native query or paginate your application

Comment: Please provide the SQL generated by that tediously verbose ORM.  Maybe we can suggest a better SQL or `INDEX`, then you can convert back to ORM-speak.

Comment: @RickJames added please check the update

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for all the columns if you are just getting a `COUNT(*)`.  The `LEFT JOINs` do no impact the count (in this case).  I think this will give you the same count:

```
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT btq_user.EMAIL)
            FROM  `btq_user`
            WHERE  btq_user.IS_DUMMY_DETAIL<>1
              AND  btq_user.DATAIN<='2018-02-28 23:59:59'
```

And this index *may* help:

```
INDEX(DATAIN)
```

**More**

This does not make sense:

```
SELECT  IF( COUNT(btq_user.id) > 1,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(btq_user.id),
                                '~',CONCAT(btq_user.datain)) ,
                   null ) as quizes
    FROM  `btq_user`
    WHERE  btq_user.EMAIL='melinbakar@hotmail.com'
      AND  btq_user.IS_DUMMY_DETAIL<>1
      AND  (btq_user.DATAIN>='2008-03-11 00:00:00'
      AND   btq_user.DATAIN<='2018-03-13 23:59:59'
           )
    ORDER BY  btq_user.DATAIN DESC
```

There is only one row (due to the aggregate function `COUNT`), so `ORDER BY` has nothing to work with.  Perhaps you wanted the `ORDER BY _inside_ the`GROUP_CONCAT`?

That needs `INDEX(email, datain)`

Comment: Thanks but i have updated the query please check. The old one was added mistakenly.thanks.

Comment: @DojoDev - Check the values from `COUNTs`.  The `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` may have inflated the values.  Be sure that they are correct before I attempt to speed up the query.

Comment: please check this here is details of the page i got from debug toolbar.
https://pastebin.com/H8TzCuR1

Comment: I commented on one of the queries.

Comment: buddy please check the new update, i found out another query which is making all the mess. Cuz i am calling that from view and for each record it is calling it.

Comment: Are you referring to a MySQL `VIEW`?  Or some other use of the term "view"?

Comment: By view i mean template in symfony not mysql view